# How to select one Radio Button and Going to that activity in android?

Tags: android

I am New To android, My Requirement is to choose one Radio Button and going to that corresponding activity in Android?
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.......

Comment: Have you at least tried to do something? I mean... do you have the checkboxes already programmed? if so, could you please provide code so that we can help?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of this for you.  This is the xml layout with two grouped radiobuttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<RadioGroup 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RadioButton
android:id="@+id/radiobutton1"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="radio 1"
/>

<RadioButton
android:id="@+id/radiobutton2"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="radio 2"/>
</RadioGroup>  </LinearLayout>
```

In the onCreate for your activity, after you setContentView to the above view, find the radiobuttons and setup checked listeners.

```
    RadioButton buttonOne = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiobutton1);

    buttonOne.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if (isChecked)
            {
                //Go to the activity for button 1 here
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityYouWantToGoTo.class));
            }
        }
    });

    RadioButton buttonTwo = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiobutton2);

    buttonTwo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if (isChecked)
            {
                //Go to the activity for button 2 here
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityYouWantToGoTo.class));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need for this is explained in those 2 guides:

- [How to deal with Radio Button](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#RadioButtons)
- [How to Start Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actcomp)